# Automapper begins mapping nullable bools incorrectly, and continues to do so until the app is rebuilt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, automapper

I've been facing an intermittent issue with automapper across a couple of different projects.

%99.9 of the time, mapping on nullable bools works properly.  However, intermittently, at some point it starts incorrectly mapping false and null values for sure, and on even rarer occasion I have seen it map false to true.

For a long time I thought it might be in my head, but today it was verified while demonstrating a new piece of functionality to my coworker.  Consistently, it was mapping null to false, and false to null.  Once it starts, it will happen with every nullable bool, as far as I can tell.

The odd thing is that it will stop doing this as soon as I rebuild the project.

On one project, we believe that the problem was solved by writing a small function that just took in the source values and gave the obvious values back, but that was on mapping from a nullable bool to a non-nullable bool.  But today, it happened from a nullable bool to a nullable bool.

And I have not one idea how to debug this.  I can't get it to reproduce with any degree of predictability, and have gone so far as to write a selenium test that ran 3000 times to attempt to trip it off, to no avail.

I have a trace.axd from the request from earlier today, if that might help out.

Can anyone give me suggestions?  We use C#, Visual Studio, IIS, AutoMapper, and .Net MVC and Entity Framework.

At this point, I'm so flustered that I don't know what other information I can give.  I'm on the high end of junior developer myself, but it was verified by a senior developer on my team today.  Feels nice to know I'm not seeing things.

Comment: Without some code+proof it's hard to help. It could be that EF is interfering somehow.

Comment: I've experienced similar weirdness with AutoMapper + EF in the wild. In our case AutoMapper simply starts returning objects with no properties set. Still unsure what causes it, but it is making me consider throwing out AutoMapper altogether.

Comment: This was from forever ago, but in case anyone was wondering - 

In my early days with AutoMapper I'd put some CreateMap code in a controller.  This was causing the inconsistent behavior, as it was only after the controller would be hit that it would become an issue.

It did, however, reveal a bug in Automapper that was submitted to Jimmy, and I believe it's been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue with AutoMapper 5.2.1 (current the latest version).
My database is returning the data correctly (I'm logging its properties) but god knows why automapper eventually begins to map my business entity class (I'm using NHibernate) to a Model with all of the properties to .net's defeault values:
Strings are beeing converted to null, integers to 0 and so on...
Curiosly if I restart the IIS application pool automapper became to works correctly back.

It's definitely an automapper bug.